# Does back trace save the line and file name?

Tags: c++

In C++ linux platform I use backtrace commands from glibc http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols in my code to debug an issue.

The backtrace look like the below:

```
./prog(myfunc3+0x5c) [0x80487f0]
./prog [0x8048871]
./prog(myfunc+0x21) [0x8048894]
./prog(myfunc+0x1a) [0x804888d]
./prog(myfunc+0x1a) [0x804888d]
./prog(main+0x65) [0x80488fb]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc) [0xb7e38f9c]
./prog [0x8048711]
```

I need to know the line and file so I can know from where each function has called.

Is backtrace command support it? 
I have read the manual didn't find anything relevant.
Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Your debugger can tell you this when you use it correctly. Google `gdb`.

Comment: `g++ -ggdb yourfile.cpp` gives you the backtrace you need

Comment: That's right but I don't want to use debugger I am writing debug prints in my code which is easier.

Answer (score 0):

compile and link with "-g to add debug information.